# FastAPI save context that will be available in endpoints

Tags: python, middleware, fastapi

My goal is to extract some information from request and put it in some global context.
First thing I tried was middleware function which does this

```
user_ctx: ContextVar[typing.Optional[UUID]] = ContextVar('user_ctx', default=None)

def save_user_ctx(request: Request):
    uid = ... # logic that extracts user uid from request header
    user_ctx.set(uid)
```

And I add this in some another middleware function for example `my_middleware`.

So it really sets the contexts but as far as I see middleware works in another thread, so if I try something like

```
@router.post('/some_url', response_model=SomeResponseModel)
def some_url(data: SomeRequestModel, auth_checker = Depends(my_middleware)):
    user_ctx.get() # >> None
```

`auth_checker` has all auth info, so middleware works okay. But `uid = user_ctx.get()` returns `None`.

This is just an example. Please

What I want to achieve is to **store some context from request in thread which serves endpoints** automatically. I mean without writing `ctx.set(smth)` as the first line of each endpoint.

I also tried to write decorator

```
def save_request_ctx(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        ctx.set(...)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

But if endpoint doesnt have `request: Request` as parameter it gets - it doesnt appear in either `args` or `kwargs`. So, also, if you can tell how to force each endpoint to have `request` as parameter without manually adding it in each endpoint function - it would also be accepted as solution.

If my explanation of what I want is complicated I'll try to clarify it.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use my [`starlette-context`](https://github.com/tomwojcik/starlette-context) for that.

In order to achieve what you want it'd be best if you subclassed [`ContextMiddleware`](https://github.com/tomwojcik/starlette-context/blob/c31b0575b9b9f91aa0b1194e0347bb1a25c1c86e/starlette_context/middleware.py#L15) and overwrote the `set_context` method. What's returned will then be available in the `context` object that you can import anywhere.

Example code

```
from starlette_context.middleware import ContextMiddleware


class YourMiddleware(ContextMiddleware):
    async def set_context(self, request: Request) -> dict:
        return {"from_middleware": True}
```

After you register this middleware, in your view/logger you can import

```
from starlette_context import context
```

and use `context["from_middleware"]`.

Notice that I prepared "plugins" for most common use cases. If you want to access request/correlation id anywhere in your app, just init middleware with

```
from starlette_context import context, plugins
from starlette_context.middleware import ContextMiddleware

middleware = [
    Middleware(
        ContextMiddleware,
        plugins=(plugins.RequestIdPlugin(), plugins.CorrelationIdPlugin()),
    )
]

app = Starlette(debug=True, middleware=middleware)
```

FastAPI uses Starlette interface so you should be good to go.

Regarding

> But if endpoint doesnt have request: Request as parameter it gets - it doesnt appear in either args or kwargs. So, also, if you can tell how to force each endpoint to have request as parameter without manually adding it in each endpoint function - it would also be accepted as solution.

I can't answer that as I never tried using a view without a request argument.

Edit: I added [`RawContextMiddleware`](https://starlette-context.readthedocs.io/en/latest/middleware.html#rawcontextmiddleware) that doesn't need the request object.

Comment: How does it handle that middleware and endpoints serves in different threads?

Comment: I will and Ill ofc try your suggestion. Big thanks.

Comment: @sashaaero how did it go in the end?